# FileExists function not working in 'for' loop in AutoIt

Tags: file, autoit

I wrote a simple script which will read from a text file, which contains the location of files, line by line, and then check if file exists. For some reason, the `FileExists` function always returns `0`, even if the file exists. This is part of my code:

```
$iFileLines=_FileCountLines($sFilePath)
For $iLineNumber=1 To $iFileLines       
     Local $sTmpLine=FileReadLine($sFilePath, $iLineNumber)
     If FileExists($sTmpLine) Then
          ;do something
     Else
          ;do something
     EndIf
Next
```

Just to clarify, every line in the text file form which script is reading is location of the file on my PC, written in the "location" way, and reading of the locations is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Better use _FileReadToArray.

```
#include <File.au3>

Local $aRecords

If Not _FileReadToArray($sFilePath, $aRecords) Then
    MsgBox(4096, "Error", " Error reading File to to Array     error:" & @error)
    Exit
EndIf

For $x = 1 To $aRecords[0]

     If FileExists($aRecords[$x]) Then
          ;do something
     Else
          ;do something
     EndIf

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed **$sTmpLine** in FileExists insead of **$sFilePath**

Pass **$sFilePath** in `FileExists` and check it

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "" (quotes) around the file location paths which is written inside the file read by your script (at `$sFilePath`), it will work.